# Инициализировать 2d массив с [длинна == кол-ву уникальных символов в строке] [счеткчик уникальных символов ]

Tags: java, массивы, циклы

Уже который день бьюсь над данным заданием , но ввиду отсуствия квалификации не могу сформировать верное решение данного задания.Регулярные вырадения юзать нельзя. Мой код:

```java
public static int[][] charEntries(String string) {
       int counter[] = new int[127];

       int l = string.length();

       for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
           counter[string.charAt(i)]++;
       char array[] = new char[string.length()];
       for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
           array[i] = string.charAt(i);
           int flag = 0;
           for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
               if (string.charAt(i) == array[j])
                   flag++; }
           if (flag == 1) {
               int[][]five=new int[string.length()][2];
               five[0][0] = string.charAt(i);
               five[0][1]=counter[string.charAt(i)];
               System.out.println(five[0][0]+"|"+ five[0][1]);
           }

       }
return null;
   }
```

Comment: Можете пример привести вроде "такая строка должна сформировать такой массив"?  По описанию не очень понятно что требуется.

Comment: string ("aassddfa") - формирует массив [4][1]/
Где в массиве  [4]  - код уникального символа ,  а подмассиве  [1]  счетчик - кол-ва вхождений этого символа в строку. Длинна массива задается в звисимости от длинны строки

Comment: Еще раз. "Такая строка должна привести к такому массиву." Приведите примеры.

Comment: строка "aassddfa" приводит к результату что в главный массив записываются значение длинны {97,115,100,102} , а в подмассивы {2,2,2,1,1}
и при вызове [0][0] - показывает 97 , в при вызове [0][1] - 2

Comment: Вы показали не двумерный массив, а два отдельных массива разной длины.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понял задачу, её можно разными способами решить. Скорее всего, тот, кто её задал, ожидает решение определенным способом. Я предлагаю такой:

```java
public int[][] getGrouping(String input){
    String unique = "";

    for(char symbol: input.toCharArray()){
        if(!unique.contains(String.valueOf(symbol))){
            unique = unique + symbol;
        }
    }

    int[][] result = new int[unique.length()][2];

    for(int i = 0; i < result.length ; ++i){
        for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
            result[i][j] = -1;
        }
    }

    for(char ch: input.toCharArray()){
        for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
            if(result[i][0] == ch){
                result[i][1]++;
                break;
            }else if(result[i][0] == -1){
                result[i][0] = ch;
                result[i][1] = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Используем дополнительную строку для получения списка уникальных символов. Затем создаем массив и инициализируем его не "символьными" значениями. Затем заполняем.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш код.
Действительно то что надо . 
Теперь осталось понять логику , что бы в будующем таких вопросов уже не было !